# Check if table exists SQL

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, exists

I have a query as below:

```
    INSERT INTO CarnetMaster.GlassLookupCapacitySpecs
(ID, CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, BORESTROKE, VINNUMBER, WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEATS, COMPRATIO, TOWCAP, STEER,
TURNCIR, HEIGHT, LENGTH, VWIDTH, KERBWT, PAYLOAD, GCM, GVM)

SELECT NEWID(), CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, [BORE-STROKE], [VIN NUMBER], WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEA, [TS COMPRAT], [IO TOWC],
[AP STE], [ER TURNC], [IR HEIG], [HT LENG], [TH VWID], [TH KERB], [WT PAYLO], [AD GCM], GV
FROM CVG86_SPE
```

How can I check if table exists, then select from the table `CVG86_SPE` and Insert? If table do not exists then it should do nothing.

Comment: please mention the DBMS that you're using. Lets say, it's sql-server, then tag so.

Comment: Did one of the answers below solve your question? If so please mark-as-answer so others in the future may benefit from your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this:
SQL 2000 syntaxis

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects  WHERE xtype='u' AND name='CVG86_SPE') 
BEGIN
             INSERT INTO CarnetMaster.GlassLookupCapacitySpecs
    (ID, CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, BORESTROKE, VINNUMBER, WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEATS, COMPRATIO, TOWCAP, STEER,
    TURNCIR, HEIGHT, LENGTH, VWIDTH, KERBWT, PAYLOAD, GCM, GVM)

    SELECT NEWID(), CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, [BORE-STROKE], [VIN NUMBER], WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEA, [TS COMPRAT], [IO TOWC],
    [AP STE], [ER TURNC], [IR HEIG], [HT LENG], [TH VWID], [TH KERB], [WT PAYLO], [AD GCM], GV
    FROM CVG86_SPE 
END
```

SQL 2005 and later:

```
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CVG86_SPE' )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CarnetMaster.GlassLookupCapacitySpecs
        (ID, CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, BORESTROKE, VINNUMBER, WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEATS, COMPRATIO, TOWCAP, STEER,
        TURNCIR, HEIGHT, LENGTH, VWIDTH, KERBWT, PAYLOAD, GCM, GVM)

        SELECT NEWID(), CODE, NVIC, RELEASE, DISCON, DRV, TORQUE, KW, [BORE-STROKE], [VIN NUMBER], WIDTH, WHEELBASE, SEA, [TS COMPRAT], [IO TOWC],
        [AP STE], [ER TURNC], [IR HEIG], [HT LENG], [TH VWID], [TH KERB], [WT PAYLO], [AD GCM], GV
        FROM CVG86_SPE
END
```

Comment: Why it will fail i have run it on my test DB and runs fine ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same in SQL Server is to use the `OBJECT_ID()` function:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('table name', 'U') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
  INSERT ...
  ...
END
```

The second parameter tells the function to search specifically for the table, not for an arbitrary object, like a stored procedure or a user-defined function.

If you are checking for the existence of a temporary table, use it like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp table name') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
  INSERT ...
  ...
END
```

(Here the second parameter is unnecessary because from the name of the object it is clear that it can only be a table.)